# How to create waiting window ( like dialog box )

Tags: android

In my application i need to send some information to server. 
This action take time - and i want to show some 'waiting sign' in the meanwhile. 
In the main Activity i dont have any place to add progess bar that will show the 'waiting' - so i want to pop up something like dialog box that will show the waiting process.

How to pop up / create this dialog box ( light box ) ?

Comment: Can u please share u code . And what do u mean by **i dont have any place to add progess bar**

Comment: that mean that my gui is very crowded and i dont have any place to add any more component.

Comment: as far as i know progressBarDialog comes as popup ... so it has nothing to do with ur gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display a Progress Dialog

Here's how you can do it -> http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/07/display-indeterminate-progress-bar-on.html

Answer (score 0):

```
mydialog = new Dialog(SplashScreen.this,
                R.style.Theme_Transparent);
        mydialog.addContentView(new ProgressBar(SplashScreen.this),
                new LayoutParams(40, 40));
        mydialog.show();
```

code to show dialog. and mydialog.dismiss() for dismiss dialog.